# What are the measure for accuracy of multilabel data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, multilabel

Consider a scenario where you are provided with KnownLabel Matrix and PredictedLabel matrix. I would like to measure the goodness of the PredictedLabel matrix against the KnownLabel Matrix.

But the challenge here is that KnownLabel Matrix have few rows only one 1 and other few rows have many 1's (those instance are multi labeled). An example of KnownLabel Matrix is given below.

```
A =[1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 1 1 0
    0 0 1 1
    0 1 1 1]
```

In the above matrix, data instance 1 and 2 are single label data, data instance 3 and 4 are two label data and data instance 5 is the three label data.

Now I have PredictedLabel Matrix of data instance using an algorithm.

I would like to know various measure which can be used to measure the goodness of the PredictedLabel Matrix against KnownLabel Matrix.

I can think of frobeinus norm difference between them as one of the measure.
But im looking for the measure such as accuracy $(=  \frac{\text{Correctly_predicted_instance}}{\text{total_instance}})$

Here how do can we define the $\rm Correctly\_predicted$ for multiple data instance?

Comment: (+1) Sidenote: Is there a specific reason that you haven't accepted an answer in the majority of your questions ? Why didn't you post a comment when the provided answer did not solve your problem ? E.g.: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/centroid-matching-problem

Answer (score 42):

(1) gives a nice overview:

[image]

[image]

The [Wikipedia page n multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification#Statistics_and_evaluation_metrics) contains a section on the evaluation metrics as well.

I would add a warning that in the multilabel setting, accuracy is ambiguous: it might either refer to the exact match ratio or the Hamming score (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239577/395857)). Unfortunately, many papers use the term "accuracy".

---

(1) Sorower, Mohammad S. "[A literature survey on algorithms for multi-label learning.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11211211207326445005&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)" Oregon State University, Corvallis (2010).

Comment: Do these definitions go against the general definitions for Precision and Recall? I have always read that precision should divide by TP+FP and recall should divide by TP+FN (the proposed definitions here do the opposite if I understood well).

Comment: No, the definitions in the paper are correct. Here $Y_i \in \mathcal{Y} = \{0, 1\}^k$ is a ground truth vector of labels for $i$th sample, and $Z_i = h(\mathbf{x}_i) = \{0, 1\}^k$ is a predicted set of labels as $h$ denotes a multi-label classifier. Perhaps, you've mistakenly mixed up $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ meanings.

Comment: for the `accuracy` measure, how do you elegantly handle cases where the denominator `|Y + Z| == 0`?

Comment: @tomasyany is referring to the text definitions (not the formulas), which do appear to be switched around.

Comment: And this AP definition looks more like mAP (mean AP), no? What's referred to as 'Accuracy' is the average IoU. The terms are quite a bit confusing overall.

Comment: @Mussri For Average Precision vs. mean Average Precision: [Average Precision in Object Detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352798/12359)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt , That does support that the definition in the survey is actually for mAP. AP would be the individual sample score, and we get the mean of that.

Comment: @ihadanny , I(|Z| == 0)

Comment: Text descriptions of recall and precision are indeed wrong (although formulas seems ok). It makes me doubt about quality of this source...

Comment: I wonder if this is implemented in any of python libraries?

Answer (score 10):

The Hamming Loss is probably the most widely used loss function in multi-label classification.

Have a look at [Empirical Studies on Multi-label Classification](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~zhangchl/publications/ictai06.pdf) and [Multi-Label Classification: An Overview](http://mlkd.csd.auth.gr/publication_details.asp?publicationID=219), both of which discuss this.

Answer (score 4):

`Correctly Predicted` is the intersection between the set of suggested labels and the set expected one. `Total Instances` is the union of the sets above (no duplicate count).

So given a single example where you predict classes `A, G, E` and the test case has `E, A, H, P` as the correct ones you end up with `Accuracy = Intersection{(A,G,E), (E,A,H,P)} / Union{(A,G,E), (E,A,H,P)} = 2 / 5`